# Get the results of match using regex pattern on complex objects

Tags: json, regex, match, jq

I have a big JSON file which I am parsing using jq. I am using regex to extract objects beginning with a certain pattern on an object attribute called "com". It works perfectly fine when I just do a basic select and return only the entries where it matched.
My query looks like :

```
jq .'["posts"][] | select(.com|test("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]")) | .com' jsontest.json > oops.txt
```

The jsontest.json looks like :

```
{"posts": [{"archived_on": 3241233, "replies": 132,"com": "Life is good , and I don't want to take anything away from it . Literally #YOLO"}]}
{"posts": [{"archived_on": 456343423, "replies": 150,"com": "The premier league is returning and I am very excited for it "}]}
```

Output:

"Life is good , and I don't want to take anything away from it . Literally #YOLO".

I want to leverage the **match(regex) or capture(regex)** function and also get the individual output match objects for the matches, which in the above case would be **#YOLO** that caused the regex to be matched.

I have been stumbling upon this problem for a few hours now. I would be really grateful if anyone could guide me on how this could be achieved.

Comment: Perhaps [`capture`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#capture\(val\),capture\(regex;flags\)) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @oguzismail I have updated the post with an example. I would be really grateful if you could help me.

Comment: @jq170727 I am thinking of more of a regex pattern/matching pair-based approach, which the match function says to do. But, I'm not getting my head around getting the matches output .

Comment: @PujanPaudel Your input and output is not clear. Provide an exact input you have and output expected to the question. We can’t answer based on assumptions

Comment: @Inian . Sorry for the confusion , I edited the input and output example

Comment: It's not clear what distinguishes the first from the second `posts`? What exactly is it you are trying to match?

Comment: @JackFleeting I am trying to get the elements with hashtags in the "com" attributes. The second post doesn't have a hashtag , but the first one does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to show the match that's made by a call to `test` is to use the idiom `match(REGEX).string`, so that in your case you could modify your program slightly to read as follows:

```
.["posts"][]
| select(.com|test("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]"))
| .com
| match("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]")
| .string
```

This would however return "#Y", whereas your question indicates you want "#YOLO", so it would appear you will want something more like the following (notice the `+`):

```
.["posts"][]
| select(.com|test("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]"))
| .com
| match("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
| .string
```

#### A more efficient solution

It would be more efficient to eliminate the call to `test`:

```
.posts[].com
| match("#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
| .string
```

#### Using `capture`

Simply wrap the REGEX in a named-capture structure of the form `(?<x>REGEX).x`.  For example:

```
.posts[].com
| capture("(?<x>#(?!(p[0-9])|([0-9])|(q[0-9]|_))[a-zA-Z0-9]+)")
| .x
```